# Default landing page not working

Tags: lightning, lightning-apps, security, configuration, visibility

I have a lightning app whose component I display using a VF page after associating it to a visualforce tab. I have done the below steps

1. Associate the custom Landing page(VF Page) to a Visualforce Tab
2. Set the Default Landing page as the Visualforce tab for an APP in the App settings.
3. In the profile, I add the APP as the Default app.

But when I login as a user of the changed profile, the Landing page is still the Home page of the APP . This is the same in classic and in Lightning mode. Is there something I am missing here ?

Comment: Maybe try removing step3. Also, ensure the VF page has access to the affected profiles.

Comment: Hello @Sumuga. This was all checked earlier. The problem arises when user enters the Org using SSO as it always enters the Home Page. As a workaround Salesforce support has asked us to add "/" to our relay state on our IDP side (Should the SignIn team do this ?)  and that way it might help us to land on default page Via SSO as well .  Any suggestion ?